# Circle curve angle

Tags: math, geometry

So I'm trying to make an animation of 2 objects orbiting around one object that we will call the sun. The distance from object 1 to the sun is 2 units and that has a constant angle at which it turns and moves on.
I assume that the farther away from the sun it is the smaller the angle so the bigger the circle, but how would you calculate this angle depending on the distance? Here is a picture:

[image: circle curve diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's just talk about how to calculate the X, Y coordinates of an object moving around the origin at a constant distance D and with angular velocity W (angular velocity is the number of degrees per second).

The angle Q that our object will make with the ray beginning at the origin and pointed at the positive X-axis is given by Q(t) = Q0 + Wt, where Q0 is the angle the object makes at time t = 0 (the initial condition). If we assume that the object begins immediately to the right of the origin, Q0 = 0, for instance.

The X, Y coordinates of the object at time t can be found using trigonometry on Q(t):

```
X(t) = D * cos(Q(t)) = D * cos(Q0 + Wt)
Y(t) = D * sin(Q(t)) = D * sin(Q0 + Wt)
```

If you have two objects at different distances from the origin/sun, then for the same angular velocity W, the object closer to the origin/sun will move with a slower speed than the one farther away. This is because to move the same number of degrees around a larger circle, the object farther away has longer actual distance to go in the same time. Assuming that the angular velocity is being measured in degrees per second, the object's speed in D's distance units per second can be found as follows:

```
V = (angular velocity / 360 degrees) * (circumference of circle)
  = (W/360) * (2*PI*D)
  = 2*PI*D*W/180
```

So, if you wanted V to be constant rather than W, you could solve this for W in terms of your desired V and D.